# How to count every word occurence in a string in a ORACLE loop?

Tags: string, oracle, count, split, procedure

I've got a problem which seems simple at first, but really isn't. I'm storing words in a table in such way that pair of strings "A B C D E" and "D E F" becomes:

```
id  value
--  -----
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
1   E
2   D
2   E
2   F
```

And i pass to my ORACLE procedure string which looks like this: "A B C D G". And now I want to check percentage of similarity between strings in the database and string passed as a parameter.

I presume that I have to use one of split functions and use an array. Later check if every word in passed string occurs in the table and then count ids. But there`s a twist: I need precise percentage value.

So, result from example above should look like this:

```
id percentage
-- ----------
1  80              -- 4 out of 5 letters exists in query string (A B C D)
2  33              -- 1 out of 3 (D)
```

So, my questions are:

- what is most effective way to split query string and then iterate on it (table?)
- how to store partial results and then count them?
- how to count final percentage value?

Every help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query would give you what you want without the need to bother with procedures.

```
select id
     , sum(case when value in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', G') then 1 else 0 ) / count(*)
  from my_table
 group by id
```

Alternatively if you **have** to pass the string "A B C D G" and get a result back you could do:

```
select id
     , sum(case when instr('A B C D G', value) <> 0 then 1 else 0 ) / count(*)
  from my_table
 group by id
```

These do involve full scanning the table or an index full scan if you use the suggested index below, so you might want to add the following where clause if you only want to find `ids` that have a percentage > 0.

```
select id
     , sum(case when instr('A B C D G', value) <> 0 then 1 else 0 ) / count(*)
  from my_table
 where exists ( select 1
                  from my_table
                 where id = mt.id
                   and instr('A B C D G', value) <> 0 )
 group by id
```

For all the queries your table should be indexed on `my_table, id` in that order.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution helped me a lot, it wasn`t exactly what I needed, but it pushed me in right direction. I`ll have to use split after all because I need to count every occurence of any value, not the whole string. So in my case I`d have to use something like: sum(case when value IN('A','B','C','D','G') then 1 else 0 ) / count(*)</br> So passed string has to be splitted after all :/

Comment: Well, it works when you change order of arguments :) instr(value,'A B C D G') doesn`t work but instr('A B C D G',value) works perfectly. Thanks Ben!

Comment: oops @Ziouas, yes... sorry about that, to used to writing it the other way around. I've edited my answer so it makes more sense now!

Comment: Ok, thanks! It took me a while to figure out why it didn`t work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [UTL_MATCH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm#CHDEAEGD)? It doesn't do exactly what you're trying to achieve, but you may find it useful if the definition of your percentage agreement isn't set in stone.

Comment: Wow, really nice set of functions, but not really my goal. Similarity of strings 'A B' and 'A C D B' should be 50% (2 exact matches), in this algorithm it`s 72% (Jaro-Wnkler) or 43% (Edit Distance). But I`ll look into it in the future. Thumbs up!